# Is it ok to change question title and content after realizing the question context is wrong?

Tags: discussion, questions, title

Sometimes when we ask questions we assume a reason behind the problem. But from the replies we get we realize that actual reason of the problem is not what we initially thought but something else.

We phrase the question title and content according to our initial assumption. The answers we get depend on how the question was asked.

So if I change the question those answers may start to look irrelevant.

And if I keep the question and title as they are, a person who is trying to find an answer to a problem, similar to what is described by the title, may get mislead. And on the other hand, a person who is trying to find a solution to a problem, similar to the actual problem of my question, may not see the question at all.

So what might be the best thing to do in such a situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution may be to edit the title to more clearly match the content of the question. If this would create a duplicate, flag for moderator attention and ask to be closed.

In my opinion, these steps would have the least negative impact.

**Update**
On ocassion you may ask a question and get responses that accurately answer the question. If, however, you realize that the question is lacking in some details that better clarify the actual problem, you will have to decide if you can provide a very brief edit explaining those details.

If you feel that the edit would disrupt continuity of answers, and the answers (as they are) do provide solutions relevant to the question ***as is***, I recommend asking a new question. It is perfectly acceptable to reference a link to your previous question and explain that there was another issue that needed to be addressed.

Comment: What if the title and content of the question match but the actual problem is not clearly depicted by the question?

Comment: @Niroshan: do you have a link to an example? If the title and content match and answers are provided that make sense - I say leave it. Ask another question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377127/sending-blocks-of-2d-array-rows-using-mpi-in-c The last code block was added later (My question is about MPI but the problem is in how use arrays)